# Monosyllabic triphthongs with R are distinguished from sequences with disyllabic realizations

Tags: british-english, rhoticity, diphthongs, triphthongs

> In British Received Pronunciation, and most other non-rhotic
> (r-dropping) varieties of English, **monosyllabic triphthongs with **R** are
> optionally distinguished from sequences with disyllabic realizations**:
>
> [aʊ̯ə̯] as in hour (compare with disyllabic "shower" [aʊ̯.ə]) [aɪ̯ə̯]
> as in *fire* (compare with disyllabic "higher" [aɪ̯.ə]) [ɔɪ̯ə̯] as in
> "loir" (compare with final disyllabic sequence in "employer" [ɔɪ̯.ə])
>
> As [eɪ̯] and [əʊ̯] become [ɛə̯] and [ɔː] respectively before /r/, most
> instances of [eɪ̯.ə] and [əʊ̯.ə] are words with the suffix "-er".
>
> Other instances are loanwords, such as *boa*.
>
> [aʊ̯ə̯, aɪ̯ə̯, ɔɪ̯ə̯] are sometimes written with ⟨awə, ajə, ɔjə⟩, or
> similarly.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triphthong#English

Do they mean actually acoustically or just notationally?

Secondly, why is the letter **r** capitalized ?

Comment: Please be aware that renowned English phonetician John Wells, author of the *Longman Pronunciation Dictionary*, **does not** believe that vowel sequences traditionally considered “triphthongs” like /aɪə/ actually are such. In [his blog posting “John Wells’s phonetic blog: triphthongs anyone?”](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/12/triphthongs-anyone.html), Wells takes issue with the traditional British idea that those are actually triphthongs. See also [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/214848/2085) regarding this matter.